# How do I change the Magento website that a customer is related to?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, customer-account

We have a multi-store 1.19ce setup.  Two stores, retail and wholesale.

What we need is customers specific to each store only, not shared.  Registration for both stores is only allowed in retail store. If customer applies for wholesale status after they have registered in retail store, they can fill out a form and we then approve them.  At this point we need to go to customer account config and assign them to wholesale store only.  However when we try to do that it is greyed out and wont let us change the website.

If I set customer configuration to global, the customer can login to both stores.  When I set the customer config to per website, the customers cannot login at all on either store.

If a customer registers for a normal account on the retail store and if I have the global customer config set to per website as default, then after they register they cannot login. When I set default customer config back to all, they can login. Totally confused here.

Can anyone share some ideas on how to do this with Magento CE?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll likely need to setup up 'roles', then a custom module with an observer to show the correct store view.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Not sure how to do that.  I checked roles but do not know how to create an observer module.  We had a developer working with us, but he had to leave because of an illness.  We are now trying to fix some of the issues still left undone. Do you know anyone that can help us?

Comment: You can hire a developer here: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer or here: http://elance.com among other places.

Comment: Thanks! Are you for hire? :)

Comment: A search for my name and latter link above would yield results to that inquiry ;)

Comment: Ok found you! How can I ask questions related to this issue without posting a job?

Comment: @timhallman I sent you a request on Elance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can just change the website_id of the customer. But there must be a reason, that magento doesn't allow this.

Some reasons which come to my mind:

- Customers can't login in their account anymore, when the website is changed
- Order is related to a customer which "doesn't exist" anymore

So you can try (and TEST TEST TEST) to just change the template to make it changeable. Maybe you have to fix a few thing, e.g. add website_id to the `customer_form_attribute` to tell magento to save it.